# Laravel route parameter is not accpeting special characters like + (plus)

Tags: php, laravel

I have this route:

```
Route::get('product/get/{project_token}/{user_id}/{id}', 'get_project')->where('id', '.*');
```

Here for the `id` param, the value can be any character like

> DRGM48/58BA
> DRGM48/78BA+BZA43B.
> 1254EBD

Now, If the `id` param value is this `DRGM48/78BA+BZA43B` then I can see that the route is not passing the value. It seems like **+** character is not accepting.

Can you tell me how can I fix it?

Comment: From how/where is that route being called/used? I'm thinking that the `+` should be encoded (or possibly decoded) somewhere along the way to avoid the situation.

Comment: From my vue. js `http.get('product/get/' + this.projectToken + '/' +  this.user_id + '/' + encodeURIComponent(params.id) )`

Comment: `+` is a URL encoded character for space, so if you URL decode your `id` param before using, it should be fine

Comment: @Tushar i did it using `encodeURIComponent `

Comment: Ah, I think I did a mistake on my PHP file I used:  `urldecode(Helper::format_field_type($id)); ` I should remove `urldecode`

Answer (score 0):

Plus sign is used to represent a space character in the query. So for this, you have to use `urlencode` and `urldecode`

Ex

```
$product_id = urlencode('DRGM48/78BA+BZA43B');
```

In controller

```
public function get_project($project_token, $user_id, $id)
{
    $product_id = urldecode($id);
    // use $product_id in your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues in my previous project. So, I have applied multiple solutions but not worked. Then I find the solution which is below.

Description: The "+" character is a reserved character in URLs and is used to represent a space. Laravel's route parameters use the "+" character as a wildcard, which means that any text after the + character will be ignored.

```html
Route::get('product/get/{project_token}/{user_id}/{id}', 'get_project')->where('id', '[A-Za-z0-9\+/]+');
```

Hope this help to you.